# Add functions from a child class into list of functions pointers in abstract parent class

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, function-pointers

I have an abstract class that has a list of function pointers, and I want to insert into that list pointers to functions in a subclass. I have the following code:

```
class Parent {
    public:
        typedef Output* (*function_pointer)(Input*);
        vector<function_pointer> compute_functions;
}
class Child : public Parent {
public: 
        Output* f1(Input* input) {}
        Output* f2(Input* input) {}
        void user_insertFunctions(){
              compute_functions.push_back(&f1);
              compute_functions.push_back(&f2);
         }
}
```

However I get the error: 
`test1_Engine.cpp:37:32: error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address ofan unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say ‘&test1_Engine::f2’ [-fpermissive]`

I have to have the functions in the child class, but the list of function in the abstract parent class. How can I do this?

Comment: `f1` and `f2` are not functions. They are class methods. Big difference. If you want them to be functions, declare them with a `static` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

f1 and f2 are class members so you can't pass them as input parameters to the vector. You can simple fix you code by changing the type of compute_functions:

```
class Input;
class Output;
class Child;

class Parent {
    public:
       using function_pointer = Output* (Child::*)(Input*);
       vector<function_pointer> compute_functions;
};
class Child : public Parent {
public: 
        Output* f1(Input* input) {}
        Output* f2(Input* input) {}
        void user_insertFunctions(){
              compute_functions.push_back(&Child::f1);
              compute_functions.push_back(&Child::f2);
         }
};
```